# Polytonic Greek in XML: it's not unicode, but what is it?

Tags: html, xml, excel, unicode, utf-8

When using XML as the output format, the Perseus vocabulary tool displays greek words in some kind of latin way. for example: **ὁ** is written as **o(**. **δέ** is written as **de/**. **οὗτος** is written as **ou(=tos**.

My question is this. Does anybody know :

a) how this way of representing polytonic greek is called? Is this a convention? I couldn't find anything online.

b) how I can convert these back to proper greek letters / words? How do I tell XML (or Excel if thats easier, I have an excel sheet with the latin spelling now, but obviously want to study the proper greek letters) to display the proper greek letters?

Comment: http://www.katabiblon.com/tools/perseus-hopperizer/

Comment: thanks, that looks great. do you know how I could go about changing my excel files from this transliteration into proper greek unicode now?